# header values inside of a POST request are set null nodejs

Tags: node.js, http-headers, nock

I have been trying to perform POST request from my test.js to a Node.js using nock. I dont  understand eventhough I pass header values, the request.payload(body) values at the node are null as the header values are getting null when they reach the server.

```
  scope = nock('http://localhost:3000')
        .post('/Channel/register', payload,headers)
        .reply(200, {status: 200});

});
request.post('http://localhost:3000/Channel/register', function(err, body) {
    console.log(err, null);
});

    request.post({url:'http://localhost:3000/Channel/register',
                headers: JSON.stringify({
                    "content-type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    'warning': "with content type charset encoding will be added by default",
                    "content-length": 50
                }),
                mode: 'no-cors',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                     Channel: "Cricket",
                     codes: "c--HOjyWVww:APA"
                })
            },  function (err,response) {
                // console.log(request);
                console.log("+response status code:", response.statusCode);
                console.log(response.failureCount);
                if (err) {
                    throw err; // => Error: Nock: No match for request POST http://foobar.com/ {"foo":"biz"}
                }
                done();
            });


});
```

Comment: If this is the [request](https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers) module then you have to take a look at the documentation. HTTP headers are not JSON and if your body is JSON then you can't have x-www-form-urlencoded as mime type.

Comment: Used the header type: 'content-type':'application/json', but still doesnot